# Axes change when using hold for plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have two `v_q` and `v_qb` plotted in separate figures, but when I plot them together in the same figure, their values change. Why?

This is the Matlab code (data is from Synopsis software):

```
v = [ 0.000E+00 2.449E-02 4.898E-02 7.347E-02 9.796E-02 1.224E-01 1.469E-01 1.714E-01 1.959E-01 2.204E-01 2.449E-01 2.694E-01 2.939E-01 3.184E-01 3.429E-01 3.673E-01 3.918E-01 4.163E-01 4.408E-01 4.653E-01 4.898E-01 5.143E-01 5.388E-01 5.633E-01 5.878E-01 6.122E-01 6.367E-01 6.612E-01 6.857E-01 7.102E-01 7.347E-01 7.592E-01 7.837E-01 8.082E-01 8.327E-01 8.571E-01 8.816E-01 9.061E-01 9.306E-01 9.551E-01 9.796E-01 1.004E+00 1.029E+00 1.053E+00 1.078E+00 1.102E+00 1.127E+00 1.151E+00 1.176E+00 1.200E+00];
v_qb = [ 1.200E+00 1.200E+00 1.200E+00 1.200E+00 1.199E+00 1.199E+00 1.198E+00 1.197E+00 1.196E+00 1.194E+00 1.190E+00 1.185E+00 1.178E+00 1.167E+00 1.153E+00 1.134E+00 1.108E+00 1.076E+00 1.034E+00 9.790E-01 9.080E-01 8.408E-01 8.005E-01 7.755E-01 7.578E-01 7.440E-01 7.327E-01 7.231E-01 7.147E-01 7.073E-01 7.006E-01 6.946E-01 6.890E-01 6.839E-01 6.792E-01 6.749E-01 6.709E-01 6.671E-01 6.636E-01 6.603E-01 6.572E-01 6.543E-01 6.515E-01 6.489E-01 6.463E-01 6.438E-01 6.415E-01 6.392E-01 6.370E-01 6.348E-01];
v_q = [ 0.000E+00 2.449E-02 4.898E-02 7.347E-02 9.796E-02 1.224E-01 1.469E-01 1.714E-01 1.959E-01 2.204E-01 2.449E-01 2.694E-01 2.939E-01 3.184E-01 3.429E-01 3.673E-01 3.918E-01 4.163E-01 4.408E-01 4.653E-01 4.898E-01 5.143E-01 5.388E-01 5.633E-01 5.878E-01 6.122E-01 6.367E-01 6.612E-01 6.857E-01 7.102E-01 7.347E-01 7.592E-01 7.837E-01 8.082E-01 8.327E-01 8.571E-01 8.816E-01 9.061E-01 9.306E-01 9.551E-01 9.796E-01 1.004E+00 1.029E+00 1.053E+00 1.078E+00 1.102E+00 1.127E+00 1.151E+00 1.176E+00 1.200E+00];

%plotting together
figure(1) 
plot(v_qb,v_q)
hold on
plot(v,v_qb)

%plotting separately
figure(2) 
plot(v_qb,v_q)
figure(3) 
plot(v,v_qb)
```

Comment: How are you plotting them in separate plots? Please edit your question so that others can try to replicate your issue.

Comment: I revised the code per your instruction. Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me.The x-axis of `figure(2)` is different from `figure(1)` and the y-axis of `figure(3)` is different from `figure(1)`. This is just so both plots can fit together. As per the documentation, `hold` does not affect axis auto-ranging. Use `axis` if you want to customize the axis values.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. The x-axis of `figure(2)` and the y-axis of `figure(3)` are different from those in `figure(1)` so the full ranges of both plots can fit together. As per the documentation and help, [`hold`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) does not affect axis auto-ranging:

> MATLAB® adjusts axes limits, tick marks, and tick labels to display the full range of data.

Use the [`axis`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) function if you want to customize the axis values. In particular, you might use [`axis manual`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#inputarg_mode) to prevent the axis ranges from changing after your first call to `plot`:

```
figure(1) 
plot(v_qb,v_q)
hold on
axis manual
plot(v,v_qb)
```

[image: using axis manual]

This of course will clip the left side (0 to 0.6) of the second call to `plot`. Not sure exactly what you want so please play around with the options.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
% Matlab M-file converted by [Custom WaveView] saved 08:19:49 Wed Feb 22 2017
v= [ 0.000E+00 2.449E-02 4.898E-02 7.347E-02 9.796E-02 1.224E-01 1.469E-01 1.714E-01 1.959E-01 2.204E-01 2.449E-01 2.694E-01 2.939E-01 3.184E-01 3.429E-01 3.673E-01 3.918E-01 4.163E-01 4.408E-01 4.653E-01 4.898E-01 5.143E-01 5.388E-01 5.633E-01 5.878E-01 6.122E-01 6.367E-01 6.612E-01 6.857E-01 7.102E-01 7.347E-01 7.592E-01 7.837E-01 8.082E-01 8.327E-01 8.571E-01 8.816E-01 9.061E-01 9.306E-01 9.551E-01 9.796E-01 1.004E+00 1.029E+00 1.053E+00 1.078E+00 1.102E+00 1.127E+00 1.151E+00 1.176E+00 1.200E+00];
v_qb = [ 1.197E+00 1.196E+00 1.194E+00 1.190E+00 1.185E+00 1.175E+00 1.161E+00 1.139E+00 1.105E+00 1.054E+00 9.774E-01 8.640E-01 7.241E-01 6.262E-01 5.471E-01 4.680E-01 3.832E-01 2.921E-01 1.988E-01 1.248E-01 8.988E-02 7.198E-02 6.078E-02 5.303E-02 4.734E-02 4.299E-02 3.957E-02 3.680E-02 3.453E-02 3.263E-02 3.101E-02 2.963E-02 2.843E-02 2.739E-02 2.647E-02 2.566E-02 2.495E-02 2.433E-02 2.377E-02 2.328E-02 2.285E-02 2.247E-02 2.213E-02 2.183E-02 2.155E-02 2.131E-02 2.108E-02 2.088E-02 2.069E-02 2.052E-02];
v_q = [ 0.000E+00 2.449E-02 4.898E-02 7.347E-02 9.796E-02 1.224E-01 1.469E-01 1.714E-01 1.959E-01 2.204E-01 2.449E-01 2.694E-01 2.939E-01 3.184E-01 3.429E-01 3.673E-01 3.918E-01 4.163E-01 4.408E-01 4.653E-01 4.898E-01 5.143E-01 5.388E-01 5.633E-01 5.878E-01 6.122E-01 6.367E-01 6.612E-01 6.857E-01 7.102E-01 7.347E-01 7.592E-01 7.837E-01 8.082E-01 8.327E-01 8.571E-01 8.816E-01 9.061E-01 9.306E-01 9.551E-01 9.796E-01 1.004E+00 1.029E+00 1.053E+00 1.078E+00 1.102E+00 1.127E+00 1.151E+00 1.176E+00 1.200E+00];
%plotting together
figure(2) 
plot(v_qb,v_q)
hold on
plot(v,v_qb)
hold on
grid on      
x = 0:1.2/10:1.2;

figure (3)
for b=-2:0.5:2
    plot(x, x+b);
    hold on
end
hold on
plot(v_qb,v_q)
hold on
plot(v,v_qb)
```